# Using xpath - How to select column data related to table header

Tags: html, xml, xpath

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Model</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>Car</td>
            <td>blue</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Above is a snippet of a highly nested html document. To get the table level I have used the following xpath

```
//th[contains(text(), "ref_code")]/following-
sibling::td[contains(text(), "197")]/ancestor::table[2]
```

How then can I edit the same xpath and select a specific table header data and the corresponding table data column like so using xpath:

ID |Product |Color

22 |Car     |Blue

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

From your comments to the answers given here:
I assume that you get the above table from an existing xpath which is :

```
//th[contains(text(), "ref_code")]/following-
sibling::td[contains(text(), "197")]/ancestor::table[2]
```

Now you want to add/edit to this xpath such that you get the values of `td` given a column for e.g. `Color`, then the below xpath should give you the `td` values for all columns given `Color` as input:

```
//td[position()<=(count(//tr/th[.='Color']/preceding-sibling::*)+1) ]
```

Assuming your first xpath works correctly, add the above xpath to that like:

```
//th[contains(text(), "ref_code")]/following-
sibling::td[contains(text(), "197")]/ancestor::table[2]//td[position()<=(count(//tr/th[.='Color']/preceding-sibling::*)+1) ]
```

Output:

```
<td>22</td>
<td>Car</td>
<td>blue</td>
```

If you want just the `Color`, use xpath :

`//td[(count(//tr/th[.='Color']/preceding-sibling::*)+1) ]`

If you want just the `Product` use xpath :

`//td[(count(//tr/th[.='Product']/preceding-sibling::*)+1) ]`

If you want just the `ID` use xpath :

`//td[(count(//tr/th[.='ID']/preceding-sibling::*)+1) ]`

Note that the xpath changes at `th[.='XXX']` where `XXX` is the selected element.

**But** if you want the output to be in the form of a table , you need to use [`XSLT`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt), because you are trying to get a transformed view of your html , not just selected elements.

Comment: Thanks but my question was pertaining to how to select the data rather that output style. What im looking for is how to select a column header e.g Color and all or some of the data for that column.

Comment: @DarthCake So given input `Color` , you want to get `ID, Product, Color` and their values. ? Please specify correctly what is the desired I/O?

Comment: Given input 'Color' desired output should be 'blue'. So basically the corresponding <td>,  be mindful this table is within a highly nested html document.

Comment: So you are asking given `Color` you expect `blue` as answer because there is a corresponding `td` to `th` i.e. `Color` is second `th` so `blue` should appear in second `td` ?

Comment: Not yet there, what im looking for is:
If `color` is selected then output should be `<td>blue</td>`
If `product` is selected then output should be `<td>car</td>` and so on

Comment: @DarthCake I tried to understand your problem so much. Please check edited answer. I added some above `But`

Comment: For some reason your answer is selecting wrong data, Please take a look at this question for clarification, I have included the whole document structure to make it easier [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370900/xpath-how-to-select-related-cousin-data)

Answer (score 0):

We seach for table data `//table//td` by position in header of column `//table//th[text()='Color']`

That `[count(element/preceding-sibling::*) +1]` is how to find element's index

So result is:

```
//table//td[count(//table//th[text()='Color']/preceding-sibling::*) +1]
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working, but if i use ----
'//th[contains(text(), "tracking_code")]/following-sibling::td[contains(text(), "197")]/ancestor::table[2]//td[count(//table//th[text()='Color']/preceding-sibling::*) <5]' ---- 
it selects everything which is not ideal as i am looking to exclude certain header column eg model.