# Xpath - How to select related cousin data

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

```
<html>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>aaa</th>
                                <th>bbb</th>
                                <th>ccc</th>
                                <th>ddd</th>
                                <th>eee</th>
                                <th>fff</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>111</td>
                                <td>222</td>
                                <td>333</td>
                                <td>444</td>
                                <td>555</td>
                                <td>666</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

How can i select specific related cousin data using xpath, The desired output would be be:

```
<th>aaa</th>
<th>ccc</th>
<th>fff</th>
<td>111</td>
<td>333</th>
<td>666</td>
```

The most important aspect of the xpath is that i am looking to be able to include or exclude certain `<th>` tags and their corresponding `<td>`tags

So based on the answers so far the closest I have is:

```
//th[not(contains(text(), "ddd"))] | //tr[2]/td[not(position()=4)]
```

Is there any way of not explicitly using `position()=4` but instead reference the corresponding `th` tag

Comment: It's good that you've included XML and expected output, but you've not stated what criteria the expected output meets -- it's not obvious.

Comment: The criteria is to select every `th` and the corresponding `td` but exclude `th` that contain "bbb", "ddd", "eee" and their corresponding `td` tags

Comment: Which programming language you use with `selenium`?

Comment: @Andersson Im using python with chrome driver

Comment: Check [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370900/xpath-how-to-select-related-cousin-data/44372700#44372700)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the best solution, but you might try

```
//th[not(.="bbb") and not(.="ddd") and not(.="eee")] | //tr[2]/td[not(position()=index-of(//th, "bbb")) and not(position()=index-of(//th, "ddd")) and not(position()=index-of(//th, "eee"))]
```

or shorter version

```
//th[not(.=("bbb", "ddd", "eee"))]| //tr[2]/td[not(position()=(index-of(//th, "bbb"), index-of(//th, "ddd"),index-of(//th, "eee")))]
```

[that returns](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Chtml%3E%0A%20%3Ctable%20border%3D%221%22%3E%0A%20%3Ctbody%3E%0A%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%3Ctd%3E%0A%20%3Ctable%20border%3D%221%22%3E%0A%20%3Ctbody%3E%0A%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%3Cth%3Eaaa%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%3Cth%3Ebbb%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%3Cth%3Eccc%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%3Cth%3Eddd%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%3Cth%3Eeee%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%3Cth%3Efff%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%3Ctd%3E111%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%3Ctd%3E222%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%3Ctd%3E333%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%3Ctd%3E444%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%3Ctd%3E555%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%3Ctd%3E666%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0A%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0A%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Fth[not(.%3D%22bbb%22)%20and%20not(.%3D%22ddd%22)%20and%20not(.%3D%22eee%22)]%20%7C%20%2F%2Ftr[2]%2Ftd[not(position()%3Dindex-of(%2F%2Fth%2C%20%22bbb%22))%20and%20not(position()%3Dindex-of(%2F%2Fth%2C%20%22ddd%22))%20and%20not(position()%3Dindex-of(%2F%2Fth%2C%20%22eee%22))]%0A&=%2F%2Fth[not(.%3D%22bbb%22)%20and%20not(.%3D%22ddd%22)%20and%20not(.%3D%22eee%22)]%20%7C%20%2F%2Ftr[2]%2Ftd[not(position()%3Dindex-of(%2F%2Fth%2C%20%22bbb%22))%20and%20not(position()%3Dindex-of(%2F%2Fth%2C%20%22ddd%22))%20and%20not(position()%3Dindex-of(%2F%2Fth%2C%20%22eee%22))]&input-format=html&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2)

```
<th>aaa</th>
<th>ccc</th>
<th>fff</th>
<td>111</td>
<td>333</td>
<td>666</td>
```

You can avoid using complicated `XPath` expressions to get required output. Try to use `Python` + `Selenium` features instead:

```
# Get list of th elements
th_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//th')
# Get list of td elements
td_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[2]/td')
# Get indexes of required th elements - [0, 2, 5]
ok_index = [th_elements.index(i) for i in th_elements if i.text not in ('bbb', 'ddd', 'eee')]
for i in ok_index:
    print(th_elements[i].text)
for i in ok_index:
    print(td_elements[i].text)
```

Output is

```
'aaa'
'ccc'
'fff'
'111'
'333'
'666'
```

If you need `XPath 1.0` solution:

```
//th[not(.=("bbb", "ddd", "eee"))]| //tr[2]/td[not(position()=(count(//th[.="bbb"]/preceding-sibling::th)+1, count(//th[.="ddd"]/preceding-sibling::th)+1, count(//th[.="eee"]/preceding-sibling::th)+1))]
```

Comment: Thanks but both xpaths are showing up as invalid in Firepath?

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but xpath seems to be the most efficient way, The html code I posted is just a snippet of a much larger file. Im working with multiple html files which are deeply nested. 
That said, your previous answer is very close to what im looking for, its just that `index-of` function does not work in xpath 1.0, do you know of a work around?

Comment: Thanks, Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Using XPath 3.0 you can structure that into

```
let $th := //table/tbody/tr[1]/th, 
$filteredTh := $th[not(. = ("bbb", "ddd", "eee"))], 
$pos := $filteredTh!index-of($th, .)
return ($filteredTh, //table/tbody/tr[position() gt 1]/td[position() = $pos])
```

Comment: Im using selenium so xpath 1.0 would be ideal solution, Thanks